# Why is my external javascript method saying it is undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this external method that will load the correct CSS file depending on screen size which works. When I added more folders/pages I realized I need to specify how many folders deep when I'm calling it so it can find the CSS files. It works on the pages that are one folder deep which just has 1 line of text to make sure it is loaded. When I try to load the index page which has pictures and stuff it loads everything except the CSS file saying "ReferenceError: Start is not defined". Why is it not defined? Please keep all solutions strictly to javascript, I don't want to use jQuery for this project.

Here is the HTML this is in the head tag

```
<script src="../Scripts/Load_CSS_Template.js"></script>
<script>Start(0);</script>
```

Here is the external javascript

```
function Start(Folders_Deep)
{ 

    if (Folders_Deep == "undefined")
    {
        console.log("I was not defined");
    }
    else
    {
        var Prefix = "";

        if(Folders_Deep == 1)
        {
            Prefix = "../";
        } 

        console.log("Browser Screen Width: " + window.innerWidth);
        console.log("Hostname: " + window.location.hostname);
        console.log("Folders_Deep: " + Folders_Deep);
        console.log("Prefix: " + Prefix);

        if (window.innerWidth <= '1400')
        {
            Get_CSS_File(Prefix + 'Mobile_Template.css'); 
        }
        else 
        { 
            Get_CSS_File(Prefix + 'Desktop_Template.css'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example isn't valid HTML. Where is the JavaScript that you included in your example actually located?

Comment: I just have the call in the head tag

Comment: Is the script file being loaded? Have you checked the Network tab of F12 tools to be sure you are not getting a 404?

Comment: Please include a jsfiddle or snippet

Comment: There is nothing in the Network tab. It loads my pictures and stuff.

Comment: @JamieHorton Have you started recording the network traffic? You should see the page and it's resources being loaded.

Comment: I've never done a jsfiddle before, but here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/b4vpk2k5/

Comment: @DaveB I don't know how to record the network traffic. How would I do that?

Comment: Yeah but where are "Mobile_Template.css" and "Desktop_Template.css" in relation to "Scripts/Load_CSS_Template.js"?  Not saying this is wrong, but it's a bit messy in my opinion.  How complex will this project be?  Would it be simpler to make one or two CSS files for everything and just use media queries?  [This article](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) has some pretty good info about the logic of it all.

Comment: Its just for my portfolio website. It doesn't have a whole lot of pages. The two Template.css files are located at the root directory. Scripts is in the root directory too. I like to keep the CSS seperate cause I find it gets overwhelmingly confusing to mix.

Comment: The media query idea is a great solution, but I really want to find out why this isn't working

Comment: This looks like a scope issue. It's possible it is attempting to call the function before your external JS file is actually downloaded.

Comment: @mason81 Scripts loaded with `<script>` tag are loaded synchonously, unless it has the `async` attribute.

Comment: How would I go about making sure the JS file is downloaded before it will execute the call without adding jQuery's document.ready?

Comment: @JamieHorton You shouldn't need to do anything. The next script shouldn't be executed until it's done loading the first one.

Comment: Do you have a public URL to the failing site?

Comment: @Barmar good to know. I thought that might be the case, but the external file not loading was the only thing that made sense to me given the "Start is undefined" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the ../ in the call to load the js file. I forgot I copied and pasted from the page that is inside a folder. Once I removed that it loaded the script.

Comment: That should have caused a 404 error when it tried to load the JS file. You said there were no errors in the console.

Comment: There was no 404 errors, just a "ReferenceError: Start is not defined" in the console.

Comment: If there was no error when trying to load the file, you must have another `Load_CSS_Template.js` in the incorrect location, but it doesn't define `Start`.

Comment: Nope just one, but I was using Firefox not Chrome. I recently was using the developer tools in Chrome and I made a similar mistake and in Chrome the console gave me a 404 error, but Firefox did not.

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS files are always in the root directory and the JavaScript is always in the directory `/Scripts` you don't need no prefix, just use the full paths `/Scripts/Load_CSS_Template.js`, `/Mobile_Template.css`, and `/Desktop_Template.css`. Otherwise use `window.location` to find out where you are and act accordingly.

```
function Start(Folders_Deep) {
    var Prefix = "";

    if (undefined === Folders_Deep) {
        console.log("I was not defined");
    } else {
        if (Folders_Deep == 1) {
            Prefix = "../";
        } else if (Folders_Deep == 0) {
            Prefix = "./";
        }

        console.log("Browser Screen Width: " + window.innerWidth);
        console.log("Hostname: " + window.location.href);
        console.log("Folders_Deep: " + Folders_Deep);
        console.log("Prefix: " + Prefix);

        if (window.innerWidth <= '1400') {
            Get_CSS_File(Prefix + 'Mobile_Template.css');
        } else {
            Get_CSS_File(Prefix + 'Desktop_Template.css');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try that it doesn't work when I am on a page inside a folder. I have a folder named Projects and a page named myprojects.html. When on this page it will not load /Desktop_Template.css cause it looks inside Projects/Desktop_Template.css

Comment: Are you sure you use `/` at the beginning of the path and not `./`? The root `/` is always the root of the page `example.com/`, so `/foobar` extends to  `example.com/foobar` no matter where you are in `example.com/`.

Comment: Saw you linked the code and checked it, found no error. Please use `window.location` in an alert to check where you are exactly. I still assume an error with the paths.

Comment: What do you mean you found no error? If you open index.html in static pages it will load all messed up and not correctly because it is not loading the css file. Using firefox in the console it says "ReferenceError: Start is not defined" I can't run window.location cause of that error.

Comment: I downed index, *css, Scripts/*js and tried it in a directory in the filesystem. I had to change the path `<script src="/Scripts/Load_CSS_Template.js">` to  `<script src="./Scripts/Load_CSS_Template.js">` because i worked in a filesystem not from a server. The JavaScript worked and gave the output `Prefix: ../` which is wrong because the CSS fiels are in the very same directory. You don't have something for `start(0)`. Mmmh, did I got it? Give me a moment, will try it and update post.

Comment: Yea that was it. I think we found it at the same time lol Thanks for your help you led me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Try this instead.

Add this to the `<head>` section in your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getScript(src, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = src;
  s.async = true;
  s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
    if (!callback.done && (!s.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(s.readyState))) {
      callback.done = true;
      callback();
    }
  };
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s);
}

function myCallback() { Start(0); }

getScript("../Scripts/Load_CSS_Template.js", myCallback);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the function to be executed when the file is loaded (not taking loading of other files and objects into account), you can simply place the Start(0) call below the function in Load_CSS_Template.js

I.e.

```
function Start(Folders_Deep)
{ 

    if (Folders_Deep == "undefined")
    {
        console.log("I was not defined");
    }
    else
    {
        var Prefix = "";

        if(Folders_Deep == 1)
        {
            Prefix = "../";
        } 

        console.log("Browser Screen Width: " + window.innerWidth);
        console.log("Hostname: " + window.location.hostname);
        console.log("Folders_Deep: " + Folders_Deep);
        console.log("Prefix: " + Prefix);

        if (window.innerWidth <= '1400')
        {
            Get_CSS_File(Prefix + 'Mobile_Template.css'); 
        }
        else 
        { 
            Get_CSS_File(Prefix + 'Desktop_Template.css'); 
        }
    }
}

Start(0);
```

-------------------- [ ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION ] -----------------------

Instead, put `Start(0)` in `<body onLoad="">` and it will be executed once everything is loaded. (Leave the script loading as-is in the html `<head>` section.)

I.e.

```
<body onLoad="Start(0)">Hello World</body>
```

Comment: The argument to `Start()` depends on where the calling page is located, so you can't hard-code it in the script.

Comment: But then it will always load with no prefix. Which doesn't help when I am on a page that is inside a folder. Like I have a project folder and a file called myproject.html. When I am on that page I need start to run with 1 as the variable.

Comment: I added another solution (see my answer above this comment).